# Passing Data Context from Unit of Work Into Repositories

Tags: c#, repository, unit-of-work

I've been using repositories for data access for some time now but have never successfully implemented anything resembling the Unit of Work pattern. I've started a new project for self-education using RavenDB and ASP.NET MVC (details that should be trivial, in theory) and am looking to establish a good way to wrap business transactions (**not** web requests) in their own units of work, but am having some difficulty doing so.

The following code snippet is what I'd *like* to see:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Role> _roleRepository;

        public UserService(
               IRepository<User> userRepository, 
               IRepository<Role> roleRepository)
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _roleRepository = roleRepository;
        }

        public void Register(User user)
        {
            using (var session = UnitOfWork.Begin())
            {
                _userRepository.Create(user);
                _roleRepository.AddToRole(user, Role.Public);
                session.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

My first stab at a unit of work interface looks something like this:

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        void Commit();
    }

    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly IDocumentSession _session;

        public UnitOfWork(IDocumentStore documentStore)
        {
            _session = documentStore.OpenSession("http://from:config");
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            _session.SaveChanges();
        }

        public static IUnitOfWork Begin()
        {
            return IoC.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _session.Dispose();
        }
  }
```

Where I'm stuck is the repositories' access to the database session. As I mentioned, I'd like to wrap **business transactions** in their own units; I'm also not keen on passing the session / context into each method, and most other solutions I've seen use static methods and / or storage in something like the web session. All of these make me a little uncomfortable; is there something key that I'm missing to this whole Unit of Work concept?

Comment: You have 2 additional options:

1. Use .Net Distributed Transaction (TransactionScope) as the Business Transaction Management as it is technology agnostic and you dont need to pass any session or context information.

2. Design you custom UnitOfWork implementation that tracks all changes made (Add, Remove, Modify) then on the Commit method co-ordinate all these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fond of the `TransactionScope` concept, and further research & discussion has led me to believe that what I am trying to do is simply not feasible.

In the end, the repositories within the `UnitOfWork`'s context need to (explicitly) know about the `UnitOfWork`. I haven't settled on which way to go just yet, but I'm going to do something like one of the following:

```
using (var session = UnitOfWork.Begin())
            {
                _userRepository.Use(session).Create(user);
                _roleRepository.Use(session).AddToRole(user, Role.Public);
                session.Commit();
            }
```

or

```
using (var session = UnitOfWork.Begin())
            {
                session.Get<IUserRepository>().Create(user);
                session.Get<IRoleRepository>().AddToRole(user, Role.Public);
                session.Commit();
            }
```

I'm not crazy about either approach; I'll mark this as the answer until I receive a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Julia Lerman has some great examples of the Unit of Work using Entity Framework.

In entity framework it is supported in the context so it is very easy to implement a unit of work.
The main problem I would see is how do you manage the order.
Example: Table A and Table B

Table B has a foreign key to Table A. 
Your unit of work would have to know to order otherwise it would error out.
I would just go with an OR/M like Nhibernate or EF.
It should make like a lot easier.